# What is the most reliable part of the user-agent string to detect Internet Explorer?

Tags: browser, internet-explorer, http

For example, does the version token always start with MSIE using Internet Explorer?

Can MSIE show up as the token of another browser?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Doesn't this really belong on StackOverflow?  And more importantly, why do you want to do this?

Comment: It isn't clear that you are doing this, but be careful not to do things like block access based on the browser used.  This really ticks off savvy users :)

Comment: Do whatever you want to do with a conditional comment on the website itself. Opera can be set to send a user agent string that cannot be distinguished from MSIE if some site thinks it only likes MSIE.

Comment: Could equally belong on Stack Overflow or Webmasters, depending on what the user is trying to do, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All versions of Internet Explorer (or at least every one that I have ever seen; certainly every one that you are likely to encounter online) contain the string "MSIE" by default.

However, there are numerous other browsers, agents, and crawlers that contain that string, most notably various versions of Opera. And of course, the user-agent string can easily be changed by users.

Therefore, you should not absolutely rely on the user-agent string to identify browsers for any critical purpose.